# How do i grab an ID generated dynamically by JQuery for Selenium test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium 2,  I managed to

1. pull out a slidebar from the left by invoking CSS code based on clicking a widget using Actions class
2. select an item from the menu list in that slide bar using Actions class
3. step 2 should have brought into view a toggle button which will roll down another menu list or roll it up depending on the toggle click
4. i am yet to get hold of the ID of this toggle (i tried XPATH, id and all that)
5. I am told this button and it's list are generated dynamically by Jquery which is pasted below.

How can i grab this toggle button , click it and then choose one item in the menu list that is rolled down ?

```
    <!-- Select Menu Style -->
    <div class="ui-widget" style="margin-left:-8">  
    <br/>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="moduleMenu" value="#{baseBean.selectedMenu}" 
            onchange="jQuery('.submitMenuSelection').click()"
            styleClass="comboboxnowidth leftSideMenuSelect " style="z-index: 0;">       
    <f:selectItems value="#{baseBean.userFeatures}"  />
    
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can't do this way. instead create a function and pass `this` as a param and then use that.

Comment: Can You provide your code a JSfiddle ? It would help in getting a solution.

Comment: How do i provide my code a JSFiddle ?